# Add table inside list in microsoft report

Tags: microsoft-reporting

I have an error when i add table inside list control in microsoft report.The error message is " The tablix ‘Tablix1’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members. "

How can i add a table in a list ??